# Can't import pocketsphinx after successful installation with conda

Tags: python, conda, pocketsphinx

I'm using conda to roll back my python env to version 3.5 so that I can install pocketsphinx.

I used `conda install -c conda-forge pocketsphinx` outlined here https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pocketsphinx

It seemed to install properly with no errors.

```
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /.../anaconda3/envs/uwu

  added / updated specs:
    - pocketsphinx


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  pocketsphinx       conda-forge/linux-64::pocketsphinx-0.8-h14c3975_1002
  sphinxbase         conda-forge/linux-64::sphinxbase-0.8.5prealpha-h14c3975_1000


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

However, it doesn't appear to import properly.

```
>>> import pocketsphinx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pocketsphinx'
```

Any idea why?

Comment: have you made sure that the correct python interpreter was called: `print(sys.executable)`

Comment: This seems to return the correct path:
```
Python 3.5.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 23 2018, 23:45:43) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/home/.../anaconda3/envs/uwu/bin/python
```

Comment: @NullSalad experiencing the exact same issue here, I have tried reinstalling the package, ensuring all dependencies are installed, ensuring that python recognizes that it is installed and that I am using the correct python executable. Did you ever manage to figure out what the issue/solution was? Thanks.

Comment: @said no I did not sadly